# pass "global" options to minted/fancyvrb

Tags: listings, highlighting, minted

Is there a way to override default options for the `minted` environment, rather than having to specify them for each and every snippet of code ?

In other words, is there an equivalent to `listings`'s `\lstset` command ?

AFAIK the `minted` package is based on `fancyvrb`, but I couldn't find anything in there either (I don't really read tex so I only looked at the documentation)

Bonus question: why is there so much blank space (about two blank lines) *after* a minted listing ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`\fvset{..}` mentioned in the documentation *several* times ...

Comment: Indeed, thanks for that. I should have *read* the manual and not skimmed through the titles. /me feels stupid.

Comment: But not in the main section; it is mentioned only in the source code without any actual examples, so it is not obvious at all.

Comment: Yes, not obvious at all, unless you spend hours to read the entire thing through. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

> Bonus question: why is there so much blank space (about two blank lines) after a minted listing ?

This has already been [asked](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2318598/1968) – and answered – on Stack Overflow.

As for minted having presets, besides the obvious `\fvset`, it doesn’t. The rationale was that you would usually define a language-specific shortcut of the minted commands for each language that you use (which usually shouldn’t be that many anyway), as explained in chapter 6 of the documentation.

(And the fact that the `minted` doc doesn’t mention `\fvset` is arguably a documentation bug. Perhaps some day I’ll come round to doing a new release.)

Comment: I couldn't find a reference to \fvset in the documentation either. Why does @Herbert claim that it is mentioned there? (I also cannot get \fvset{} to work.)

Comment: @StephenBosch Probably just an honest mistake. The `minted` documentation *does* mention somewhere that it’s built on top of `fancyvrb`, and *its* documentation mentions `\fvset`.