# Set my own minted default options inside a class

Tags: minted, package-options

Is there a way that I can set minted options inside a class? I want to set my own defaults format for minted inside a custom class that I have.

Comment: are these of any help ? [pass “global” options to minted/fancyvrb](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8025/15717) and [Possibility to pass options to packages](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/66591/15717)

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). Usually, we don't put a greeting or a "thank you" in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here to say "thank you" to users who helped you](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Comment: @texenthusiast- How can i set all the options that are in minted documentation using fancyvrb? I want to set minted parameters like: gobble, funcnamehighlighting, label, labelposition etc. Can i set this options trought fancyvrb inside a custom made class?

Comment: @Starlays [minted](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/minted/minted.pdf) is based on [fancyvrb](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/fancyvrb/fancyvrb.pdf), `fancyvrb` options are controlled by `\fvset{..}` and `minted` options via Defining shortcuts using `\newminted{..}{..}`.

Comment: @texenthusiast it is ok if i define shortcuts in my class file? As i said, i want to define the default formats for minted so i will not make the same settings for each code listing... i am a beginner and i want to learn, i need to understand how things are working so if you can give me some commands so i can document it will help me a lot.

Comment: @Starlays you can define all your macros and `\newminted` shortcuts(environment) in [separate `custom.sty` file](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63358/15717) and `usepackage{custom}`. Alternatively(simple) place all macros and `\newminted{}{}` in [`preamble`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/preamble) so you/all can explicitly see what your style for eg: [Defining a command for a minted environment](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/25196/15717). PS: I am also a newbie trying to help you.

Comment: @texenthusiast thank you, this las link helped me allot. Thank you once more.

Comment: @Starlays you can answer your question with more code options details to gain some reputation and help future users. it's self learning for you. else i can answer.

Comment: @texenthusiast you can do it so i can rate it.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem by using shortcuts.

I have done like so in my .cls file:

```
...
%php syntax highlight
\RequirePackage[chapter]{minted}
\definecolor{mintedbackground}{rgb}{0.95,0.95,0.95}
\newmint{php}{
bgcolor=mintedbackground,
fontfamily=tt,
linenos=true,
numberblanklines=true,
numbersep=12pt,
numbersep=5pt,
gobble=0,
frame=leftline,
framerule=0.4pt,
framesep=2mm,
funcnamehighlighting=true,
tabsize=4,
obeytabs=false,
mathescape=false
samepage=false, %with this setting you can force the list to appear on the same page
showspaces=false,
showtabs =false,
texcl=false,
}
...
```

And in my .tex document i have done like this:

```
....  
 \begin{document}
     \begin{listing}[H]
         \begin{phplisting}
 <?php
 $foo = 'bar';

 class foobar
 {
     //some var that can be accesed from outside
     protected $bar = 'foo';

     public function getvarvalue() {
         return $bar;
     }
  }
        \end{phplisting}
     \caption{Example of a listing.}
    %\label{lst:example}
    \end{listing}
\end{document}
```